# How to determine if a bit is set in a hex-decimal string?

Tags: java, bitset

I have a string in hex format like:

```
AAE04471
```

In my opinion, in binary view this string must look like:

```
10101010 11100000 01000100 01110001
```

I'm trying to determine if 32 bit is set like this:

```
 String s = "AAE04471";
 byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
 System.out.println("Length bytes[] = " + bytes.length);
 BitSet bitset = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
 System.out.println("Length of bitset = " + bitset.length());
 System.out.println("Look of bitset = " + bitset.toString());
 System.out.println("32 bit is " + bitset.get(31));
```

I get a 'false' result:

```
Length bytes[] = 4
Length of bitset = 31
Look of bitset = {1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 14, 15, 18, 22, 24, 28, 29, 30}
32 bit is false
```

The result is a completely different and strange bit order!

```
01010101 00000111 00100010 1000111
```

What am I doing wrong?

How to correctly determine whether a bit is set in a hex-string?

Comment: Your interpretation of the bitset is wrong. Bit 0 is the *rightmost* bit (least significant, you may say), and bit 31 is the *leftmost* bit. So your bitset should be read in reverse to what you made of it. In addition, it interprets the endianness differently.

Comment: Bit positions: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0, 8+7 8+6 8+5 8+4 8+3 8+2 8+1 8+0, 16+...,

Comment: Does this have to work with arbitrary large strings? Are you only interested in the 32nd bit?

Comment: It's must work with arbitrary large strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked this together quickly: This solution does not convert the whole string into a number first, but tries to pick out the right character before checking the bit:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            test("DEAD", i);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isBitSet(String hex, int bit) {
        int n = bit >> 2;
        int last = hex.length() - 1;
        if (n < 0 || n > last) return false;
        char c = hex.charAt(last - n);
        int v = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c), 16);
        int mask = 1 << (bit & 3);
        return (v & mask) != 0;
    }

    public static void test(String hex, int bit) {
        boolean set = isBitSet(hex, bit);
        System.out.format("%s, bit %2d, %s%n", hex, bit, set ? "set" : "not set");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
DEAD, bit  0, set
DEAD, bit  1, not set
DEAD, bit  2, set
DEAD, bit  3, set
DEAD, bit  4, not set
DEAD, bit  5, set
DEAD, bit  6, not set
DEAD, bit  7, set
DEAD, bit  8, not set
DEAD, bit  9, set
DEAD, bit 10, set
DEAD, bit 11, set
DEAD, bit 12, set
DEAD, bit 13, not set
DEAD, bit 14, set
DEAD, bit 15, set
```

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation `bitnr` has to be at least 1. Basically one-indexed. I've added a little error handing to ensure `bitnr` stays within the bounds of the hexadecimal.

It finds the exact 1-length `substring` in question, and uses `bitwise OR` to identify if the particular bit is set:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471",1));          // true
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471",17));         // false
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471",32));         // true
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471AAE04471",32)); // true
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471AAE04471",40)); // false
    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471AAE04471",64)); // true
//    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471AAE04471",0));  // AssertionError
//    System.out.println(bitSet("AAE04471AAE04471",65)); // AssertionError
  }

  private static boolean bitSet(String hexString, int bitnr) {
    if (bitnr < 1 || hexString.length() * 4 < bitnr) {
      throw new AssertionError("bitnr is out of bounds");
    }

    // add 3 to the bitnr to make division by 4 go to correct index
    String bitString = hexString.substring(hexString.length()-(bitnr+3)/4,
                                           hexString.length()-(bitnr+3)/4+1);
    int check = Integer.parseInt(bitString,16);
    int OrInt = 1 << (bitnr + 3) % 4; // add 3 to the bitnr to make % 4 go to 3 for highest.
    return (check & OrInt) == OrInt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it for big hexadecimal numbers is as follows:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "AAE04471";
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal string: " + hex);

        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hex, 16);

        String binary = bigInt.toString(2);
        System.out.println("Binary string: " + binary);

        System.out.println("\nBit information:");
        System.out.println("32nd bit is " + (binary.charAt(binary.length() - 32) == '1' ? true : false));
        System.out.println("31st bit is " + (binary.charAt(binary.length() - 31) == '1' ? true : false));
        System.out.println("30th bit is " + (binary.charAt(binary.length() - 30) == '1' ? true : false));

        // Alternatively,
        System.out.println("\nBit information using an alternative method:");
        System.out.println("32nd bit is " + bigInt.testBit(31));
        System.out.println("31st bit is " + bigInt.testBit(30));
        System.out.println("30th bit is " + bigInt.testBit(29));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hexadecimal string: AAE04471
Binary string: 10101010111000000100010001110001

Bit information:
32nd bit is true
31st bit is false
30th bit is true

Bit information using an alternative method:
32nd bit is true
31st bit is false
30th bit is true
```

---

**[Update]**

Now, I have devised a way which will work for a hexadecimal number of any length. Given below is the solution along with a couple of tests:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "AAE04471";
        String binary = hexadecimalToBinary(hex);
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + hex);
        System.out.println("Binary: " + binary);
        System.out.println("Is bit number 32 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 32));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 31 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 31));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 30 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 30));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");        
        hex = "AAE044710C0000000000000000FF0000";
        binary = hexadecimalToBinary(hex);
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + hex);
        System.out.println("Binary: " + binary);
        System.out.println("Is bit number 32 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 32));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 31 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 31));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 30 set: " + isBitSet(binary, 30));
    }

    static String hexadecimalToBinary(String hexadecimal) {
        String binary = hexadecimal;
        String[] hexDigits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        String[] hextoBinaryDigits = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001",
                "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111" };
        for (int i = 0; i < hexDigits.length; i++)
            binary = binary.replaceAll(hexDigits[i], hextoBinaryDigits[i]);
        return binary;
    }

    static boolean isBitSet(String binary, int bitNumber) {
        if (bitNumber > binary.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        return binary.charAt(binary.length() - bitNumber) == '1' ? true : false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hexadecimal: AAE04471
Binary: 10101010111000000100010001110001
Is bit number 32 set: true
Is bit number 31 set: false
Is bit number 30 set: true
---------------------------------------------
Hexadecimal: AAE044710C0000000000000000FF0000
Binary: 10101010111000000100010001110001000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000
Is bit number 32 set: false
Is bit number 31 set: false
Is bit number 30 set: false
```

---

**[2nd Update]**

Finally, I have devised a way which will work for a hexadecimal number of any length and that too, without converting the whole hexadecimal number into a binary number. Rather, this method converts just one hexadecimal digit (the hexadecimal digit where lies the bit number whose status is to be found) into binary string. Given below is the solution along with a couple of tests:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "AAE04471";
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + hex);
        System.out.println("Is bit number 32 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 32));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 31 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 31));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 30 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 30));
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        hex = "AAE044710C0000000000000000FF0000";
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + hex);
        System.out.println("Is bit number 32 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 32));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 31 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 31));
        System.out.println("Is bit number 30 set: " + isBitSet(hex, 30));
    }

    static boolean isBitSet(String hex, int bitNumber) {
        if (bitNumber > hex.length() * 4) {
            return false;
        }
        int i = bitNumber % 4 == 0 ? bitNumber / 4 : bitNumber / 4 + 1;

        // Get the hexadecimal digit where lies the bit number whose status is to be
        // found.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(hex.charAt(hex.length() - i));

        // Get the decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal digit
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 16);

        // Convert the binary equivalent of the hexadecimal digit into 4-digit string by
        // left-padding 0
        String binaryStringIn4Digits = String.format("%1$" + 4 + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(n)).replace(' ', '0');

        return binaryStringIn4Digits.charAt(3 - bitNumber % 4) == '1' ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hexadecimal: AAE04471
Is bit number 32 set: false
Is bit number 31 set: true
Is bit number 30 set: false
----------------------
Hexadecimal: AAE044710C0000000000000000FF0000
Is bit number 32 set: false
Is bit number 31 set: false
Is bit number 30 set: false
```

I hope, all these different kinds of solutions help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, your sample is work. But with string , for sample, "AAE044710C0000000000000000FF0000" is not work. What could be the error?

Comment: I understand that testBit() work in reverse order for each byte,    System.out.println("Bit " + i + ": is set " + bigInt.testBit(bigInt.toString(2).length() - (i + 1))); it's work correctly

Comment: No, `testBit` does not work in reverse order; it works from right to left i.e. the first bit from right is tested with `testBit(0)`, the second from the right is tested with `testBit(1)` and so on...This way, 32nd from right (or the left most bit in the binary string printed in the output) is tested with `testBit(31)`.

Comment: I have posted an update which will work of a hexadecimal number of any length. I hope it fulfils your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I want to offer my solution based on your advice (not the most optimal but it works at 100%):

```
 private static boolean bitSet(String hexString, int bitPos)  {
        if (bitPos < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bit position '" + bitPos + "' must be > 0");
        }
        if (hexString == null || hexString.trim().length() == 0 || hexString.trim().length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HEX string '" + hexString + "' is bad");
        }
        hexString = hexString.trim();

        StringBuilder bitString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
            String byteStr = hexString.substring(i, i + 2);
        //    System.out.println("HEX byte '" +  byteStr + "'");
            String binary = new BigInteger(byteStr, 16).toString(2);
        //     System.out.println("binary '" +  binary + "'");
            if(binary.length() < 8 ) {
                binary = "00000000".substring(0, 8 - binary.length()) + binary;
            }
            bitString.append(binary);
        }

        System.out.println(bitString);

        if (bitString.length() < bitPos) {
            System.out.println(bitPos + "-nd bit is not contain in HEX  '" + hexString + "'");
            return false;
        }

        System.out.println(bitPos + "-nd bit is " + (bitString.charAt(bitPos - 1) == '1'));
        return bitString.charAt(bitPos - 1) == '1';
    }
```

Tests:

```
    bitSet("0101", 8);
    bitSet("AAE04471", 32);
    bitSet("AAE044710C0000000000000000000000", 32);
    bitSet("AAE044710C000000000000000000000", 32);
```

Outputs:

```
0000000100000001
8-nd bit is true
10101010111000000100010001110001
32-nd bit is true
10101010111000000100010001110001000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
32-nd bit is true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HEX string 'AAE044710C000000000000000000000' is bad
```